# CRM 4.0 search for team members

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

How can you search for all members of named team(s) in Dynamics CRM 4.0? I am unable to create this advanced search, and I am wondering if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like its possible from the advanced search but here is the SQL:

```
SELECT FSU.fullname
FROM FilteredTeam FT
LEFT OUTER JOIN FilteredTeamMembership FTM
ON FTM.teamid = FT.teamid
LEFT OUTER JOIN FilteredSystemUser FSU
ON FTM.systemuserid = FSU.systemuserid
WHERE FT.name = 'TEAM_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

In CRM 4.0, this search is not possible and must be done via SQL query/report, however in CRM 2011 it is a straight forward advanced search.